How to validate custom field data in Django?
I have this models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
# Create your models here.

class User(AbstractUser):
    class genders(models.TextChoices):
        MALE = 'MALE'
        FEMALE = 'FEMALE'
    
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20,unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField()
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6,choices=genders.choices,default=None)
    birthday = models.DateField()

    def verify_gender():
        super().clean()
        if User.gender not in User.genders:
            raise ValidationError("Choice must be either 1 or 2.")
        return User.gender
        
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

My goal is to not let any non correct data enter gender field
I didn't test in django admin, but when doing it through django shell, something like
gender='BLABLABLA' No error is returned
I thought it was a problem with the function verify_gender but I honestly can't see any error, everything works well so it's in the logic of the model

To ensure that only valid choices are entered in the gender field of your User model in Django, you need to properly implement a custom validation method and then call it in the clean method of the model.
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db import models

class User(AbstractUser):
    class Genders(models.TextChoices):
        MALE = 'MALE'
        FEMALE = 'FEMALE'
    
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField()
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=Genders.choices, default=None)
    birthday = models.DateField()

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        self.verify_gender()

    def verify_gender(self):
        if self.gender not in self.Genders.values:
            raise ValidationError("Invalid gender choice. Must be 'MALE' or 'FEMALE'.")
        
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

Instance Method for Validation: The verify_gender method is defined to check the value of gender. This method now correctly refers to the instance attribute self.gender.
Clean Method: The clean method is overridden to call the verify_gender method. The super().clean() call ensures that any validation logic in parent classes is also executed.
Testing in Django Shell
from yourapp.models import User
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

# Create a new user with valid gender
try:
    user = User(username='testuser', email='test@example.com', password='password', gender='MALE', birthday='2000-01-01')
    user.clean()  # Explicitly call clean to test validation
    user.save()
    print("User created successfully with valid gender.")
except ValidationError as e:
    print("Validation error:", e)

# Create a new user with invalid gender
try:
    user = User(username='testuser2', email='test2@example.com', password='password', gender='BLABLABLA', birthday='2000-01-01')
    user.clean()  # Explicitly call clean to test validation
    user.save()
    print("User created successfully with invalid gender.")
except ValidationError as e:
    print("Validation error:", e)


Did you create this answer with ChatGPT?

yes got some help in testing part @DarkBee
